# ADT Installation error

Tags: android, eclipse, repository, adt

Im having a problem during I install ADT in eclipse Helios in Windows XP.. after I put this https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ in Repository, it says Duplicate Location and I can't click for the next step..Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Start development for Android in Eclipse](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/05/05/start-development-for-android-in-eclipse/)

> Now we must install ADT Plugin. For
>   that we must launch Eclipse ( go to
>   C:\Android\Eclipse and double click on
>   eclipse.exe ) waiting for eclipse to
>   be loaded. After eclipse is loaded
>   successful we are going to Help
>   ->Install New Software and there in the field work with we select this
>   url:
>   https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
>   and press Enter button. Then, in
>   appeared tree Developer Tools we
>   select all subtrees and press Finish
>   button. After all plugins will be
>   installed Eclipse will suggest you to
>   restart it. Press Restart Now. After
>   restart we will have Eclipse with
>   installed ADT Plugin.

Yesterday I try in [this way](http://vitobrothersoft.com/2011/05/05/start-development-for-android-in-eclipse/) and all goes right, I install eclipse at home and run application on it. May be you can check it.

Comment: I have check  https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ this url now and it give 404 error may be something happens with server and you must wait some time ...

Comment: Thanks ViTo Brothers Apoyan but after I follow your suggestion, after I selected all the trees of developer tools, and selected NEXT button theres a problem its says:  The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Comment: "See the details." and what details say ?

Comment: it says: Cannot complete the request.  See the error log for details.
"Android DDMS" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Development Tools" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Hierarchy Viewer" will be ignored because it is already installed.
"Android Traceview" will be ignored because it is already installed.

Comment: @Missy, so.... all are already installed. You do not need to install them again....

Comment: @Missy yes ... You have installed it, @Dante Jiang is Right. Why you want to install it again. May be you can try uninstall all and start again)

Comment: I suggest Missy to go onto next step of Android Tutorial. Just skip installation as it has been done.

Comment: Thanks Guys, I learned that those are already installed, and now Im on my next step.  thanks thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error message: "Duplicate location". Strange because the location is not in my list of sites.

I got rid of it downloading using http instead of https, though I understand this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

try software update 
and in  box mention mobile and device development 
there u see adt install it

Answer (score 0):

i do this and it is successful
 first open   help > install new software > write in he field of work with this url
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

this will succeed i try it

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a connection timeout originally?

I had this as I was using a weak connection. I got a 'good' connection and the same error appeared. Try removing the 's' from https and it will try to install to a new location.

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Under linux, I have successfully added this repository by removing the files from eclipse folder. Of course make a backup before removing any files.

```
p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/pdtProfile.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.prefs
p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/pdtProfile.profile/.data/.settings/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.prefs
```

But before that I had same error. I was trying to add the repository to install plugin but instead i was receiving the error "Duplicate location" even if that record was not displayed in  "Available software sites" window.

---

EDIT:
Careful. This will delete other update/install software locations. You could eventually search and replace existing links from files above. But I did it my way, faster ( i don't need other software repository locations)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Help ->Install New Software and then click in "Available software sites", a list of sites and folders will appear to you, so look for the one you want to remove (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/), click at that, then click to remove. I did so and worked :)
Sorry by the bad English.

Answer (score 0):

Help ->Install New Software then check for "What is already installed".
Uninstall those things and then restart your eclipse. And then follow the same procedure you 
are currently following.